# Two progress bars visible and keyboard also

Tags: bug, android-app

1. Go the Stack Overflow site.
2. Click on search bar.
3. Change question type.
4. two progress bars and a keyboard are visible.[image]

It happens when connection is slow.

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: Motorola
- Device Model: XT1706

  - OS Version: 6.0 (XT1706_S131_160905_ROW)