# Double dialog boxes visible

Tags: bug, android-app

I am not sure if this issue has been reported or not. However when I filter the questions from right side filter menu like votes etc, I can see two dialogs.

[image: double dialog]

- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: Xiaomi
- Device Model: MI MAX 2

  - OS Version: 7.1.1 (V8.5.9.0.NDDMIED)

Comment: It should be noted that I see a similar spinner, and a similar issue when loading Google Drive in Edge. Are you guys using a Google spinner? I think they fubared it.

Comment: Also partial duplicate of your own post too: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286768/